# App Pool on IIS gets Hanged sporadically and we see white page on MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We are having an mvc4 application on IIS 8. This application had a dedicate app pool.
This app pool gets hanged sporadically and  the only solution to get the application back up and running is doing an IIS reset. After IIS reset, it starts working normally.
When I look into eventviewer, I see the message

**"A worker process '' serving application pool 'xxx' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number."**

This issue occurs only in our customer site and it works fine in our environment.

I looked into IIS logs and it does not give much information.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works to manually recycle the app pool in the same situation. 
Have this issue with IIS on a 2012R2.

Don't have a clue to why it hangs, could maybe be EF or OrmLite db framework deadlocks or such..